# Android Camera for Email

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, camera

I am a newbie in Android development.

I want to develop app that can take picture with camera, the picture will be displayed on the screen automatically and will be sent as an attachment (without user selection) to an email address.

Also, I want the picture to be sent to an email addresses which are imbedded in the app.

Finally, can the picture be sent to GSM phones using other means (like mms, etc) other than email.

**1.    Camdemo.java**

...........................

```
   public class Camdemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   EditText editTextEmail, editTextSubject, editTextMessage;
   Button btnSend, btnAttachment;
   String email, subject, message, attachmentFile;
   Uri URI = null;

   private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 101;

   int columnIndex;

   Button b1, b2;
   ImageView iv;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camdemo);

    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTo);
    editTextSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
    editTextMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
    btnAttachment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAttachment);
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

    //Finding Camera buttons and image
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //Declaring Camera onclick listerner
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
    //  End of Camera 1

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // Camera
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Bitmap bp = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
    iv.setImageBitmap(bp);


    //
    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        /**
         * Get Path
         */
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        attachmentFile = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        Log.e("Attachment Path:", attachmentFile);
        URI = Uri.parse("file://" + attachmentFile);
        cursor.close();
    }
}

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == btnAttachment) {
        openGallery();

    }
    if (v == btnSend) {
        try {
            email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
            subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString();
            message = editTextMessage.getText().toString();

            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    new String[] { email });
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    subject);
            if (URI != null) {
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);
            }
            emailIntent
                    .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
                    "Sending email..."));

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Request failed try again: " + t.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

  }

  public void openGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
            PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy () {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_camdemo, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**2.    Camdemo.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="#999fff"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="Email Address!"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/abc"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Camera"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="or"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAttachment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="attachment"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSubject"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextTo"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:hint="Subject"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextSubject"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:hint="type message here!"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextMessage"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Send" />

 </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

**3.    Camdemo manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fastrakserve.www.camdemo" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
<uses-feature   android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                android:required="false"> </uses-feature>
<uses-feature   android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
                android:required="false">
</uses-feature>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".Welcome"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name=".Camdemo"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: *Why do men have nipples?*